# Fabric JS - Can i save canvas as image but with background from <img> tag?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I put the **canvas** element in the **div** and the **img** element for the background. Of course I can use `canvas.toDataURL('image/png')`, but that only saves all objects that are inside the canvas element, I want to save everything in `div id="custom-cloth"` as image, how to do this?

for example code

```
<div id="custom-cloth">

        <!-- Tshirt Image -->
        <div class="w-full h-[38rem] overflow-hidden">
            <img id="img" src="http://sakaw.test/storage/editor/depan.png" class="mx-auto"> <--- Here is the background
        </div>

        <!-- Canvas -->
        <div
            class="absolute top-20 inset-x-0 w-[17rem] h-[30.5rem] mx-auto border-2 border-dashed border-transparent rounded-lg hover:border-orange-500">
            <canvas id="c"></canvas>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Output code displayed

[image: Screenshot]

sorry I'm not good at explaining

Comment: Personally I would load the T-shirt image and also draw it in the canvas. Then you can use `toDataUrl()`. It's the simplest solution. Added bonus is that you can make everything pixel-perfect instead of hoping that CSS will align perfectly with canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your end objective is to convert dom to an image.
May be you could try out dom-to-image https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image

```
domtoimage.toJpeg(document.getElementById('my-node'), { quality: 0.95 })
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'my-image-name.jpeg';
        link.href = dataUrl;
        link.click();
    });
```

Here is the codesandbox demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/dom-node-to-png-10odz2

Comment: this is worked but i got error in console about `while reading CSS rules from https:blablabla, SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules`